# Trying to do a fb apprequest using Koala but access token expired. How should I handle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I know this question of expired tokens has been asked many times. But I couldn't find one that fit my situation. Basically I want to make a fb apprequest to the user regardless if he/she is online or offline on Facebook.

Also, I am confused with Facebook documentation. So appreciate if someone could answer the questions I have below.

- Facebook access token expires immediately after a user signs out of Facebook unless it is a long-lived token ?
- Say user A access token has expired. Is it possible for me to get a new access token without the user A going back to my canvas application ?
- When I authenticate a user do I get a short-lived token which I can then extend the validity if I want to or do I get a long-lived token by default ?

Below is the code I use to do a fb request using Koala:

```
begin
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
  graph.put_object("me", "apprequests", {:message => "..."})
rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError
  # Assume a user has a short-lived token and hasn't visit my application for a long time. 
  # Is it possible to get a NEW long-lived token here without the user going to my application again 
  # (assume the user did not remove my application) ? If Yes, how to do that using Koala ?
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Facebook access token expires immediately after a user signs out of Facebook unless it is a long-lived token ?

Yes.

> Say user A access token has expired. Is it possible for me to get a new access token without the user A going back to my canvas application ?

The user has to interact with your app in some way for you to get a new token. That interaction doesn’t have to be visiting your actual canvas page, it can f.e. also be a call to FB.getLoginStatus on a page he’s visiting.

> When I authenticate a user do I get a short-lived token which I can then extend the validity if I want to or do I get a long-lived token by default ?

If you’re doing server-side authentication, you’ll get a long-lived one. Doing it client-side you’ll get a short-lived token, which you than may exchange for a long-lived one.

But that’s all clearly described here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Thanks so i guess it's impossible to send a fb app request to users that already have expired access tokens since they need to interact with my app in some way to generate new access tokens ?

Answer (score 4):

I came across [this post](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/23#issuecomment-15565902) which adapts code from the [Railscast on Facebook](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) to show how you can exchange the short-lived token for the 60-day one:

**user.rb**

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)

    # immediately get 60 day auth token
    oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"])
    new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info auth.credentials.token

    new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
    new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = new_access_token #originally auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = new_access_expires_at #originally Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the rails cast koala tutorial connection with this:

```
def facebook
  if self.facebook_expires_at < Time.now
    oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(ENV["FACEBOOK_KEY"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"])
    new_access_info = oauth.exchange_access_token_info self.facebook_token

    new_access_token = new_access_info["access_token"]
    new_access_expires_at = DateTime.now + new_access_info["expires"].to_i.seconds

    self.update_attributes!(:facebook_token => new_access_token,
                          :facebook_expires_at => new_access_expires_at )
  end
  @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(self.facebook_token)
  block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook

  rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
    logger.info e.to_s
    nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I had to deal with as well. I am using Devise to create users off of Facebook users for authentication with authentication tokens expiring. When a token expires, there isn't a way to renew the token without getting the user to reauthorize your app. So in my case I just have to destroy the authentication record and the user has to reauth. The rescue looks something:

```
  rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
    if e.message.include?("OAuthException: Error validating access token:")
      Rails.logger.error "Facebook access token not valid for: #{my_model.facebook_authentication} with #{e}"
      my_model.facebook_authentication.destroy
    else
      Rails.logger.error "FacebookApi#perform Koala Error with #{e}, model_id:#{model.id}"
    end
  end
```

Hope this at least helps you along your way. Be interested to know if you come across another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple just update your token in your DB when the user sign in through facebook. Every time user sign sign in update your DB, just get the token from the HASH and update token. By doing this you can have token that never expires. I did it today and it is working too.